# Stop navigation flickering on page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've a nav bar that displays either login or logout etc depending on whether a user is logged in or not.

I'm using this :

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var loggedIn = <?php echo json_encode($general->loggedIn()); ?>;
            $("#loggedIn").toggle(loggedIn);
            $("#loggedOut").toggle(!loggedIn);
        });
    </script>
```

to determine which links should be displayed.

I't all works fine except I've started to notice a split second flicker on page refresh when I'm logged in.
The nav / links are in the header and so present on every page.

When logged in and navigating to a different page the profile link flicks to login and then back again to profile.  It was working fine before but I'm assuming it's now taking slightly longer for my page to load due to images etc so the flicker has become more visible.

Is there a solution?  I'm new to ajax/jquery etc so not sure how to solve myself.

Comment: You can try putting this in the `<head>` section of the page to try to get it to run before the rest of the page is built (thus setting this before the load). But if you are using PHP, why toggle this with javascript? Can you not build the login/log out links with PHP, thus they would be there before the page loads?

Comment: @robooneus - I had it all set up via PHP.  Worked beautifully but then I wanted a drop down login box which required Ajax and after many hours searching and asking for help on SO this has been the only way to get it to function as intended :) I'll pop it in head and see if it helps.

Comment: Putting in head doesn't seem to solve:(

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of this (not sure if possible/easy to adapt to a fiddle as it is PHP)? Also, perhaps try using window.onLoad() to specify the function... may work--just trying to get the function to run before the page loads may fix it.

Comment: @robooneus - I don't think a fiddle could replicate it as it needs a page refresh? How might I go about using the window.onLoad?

Comment: I tried : window.onload = function(){
                $(function() {
                    var loggedIn = <?php echo json_encode($general->loggedIn()); ?>;
                    $("#loggedIn").toggle(loggedIn);
                    $("#loggedOut").toggle(!loggedIn);
                });
            }
Not sure if it's the correct way but still didn't solve

Comment: That is what I meant -- wasn't sure. Have you tried setting them to display:none; by default then only .show() the one that you want? Or is that what you are doing already?

Comment: @robooneus - that is what I'm doing. It's a quick flash but if someone has a worse net connection that could be quite irritating.  And I don't think it's as good as it could be.

Comment: @SteveGreen I'm under the impression that it may not be your `JS` causing the fault, but may very well be a `CSS` issue. I had the same problem a few months back, being an oversized image that was reduced to fit to screen using `max-width:100%;`. Look into that, if you have some heavy CSS happening. Just saying.

Comment: @fred, Cheers for the advice.  It's not 'heavy' heavy but it's an option to explore.  I can also sometimes notice it start in the middle of the scrren and then shift over to where it's supposed to be.  CSS overhaul required? -.-

Comment: @SteveGreen You're welcome. Maybe not a CSS overhaul, but a `checkup` worth looking into. Do you have any images set to `width:100%;` or `max-width:100%;` or set to other (forced) value?

Comment: @Fred, Now you mention it.  The header is divided into 3 divs.  the centre contains an image 100% width(of that div) - think I'll remove and see what changes.

Comment: @SteveGreen Give it a try and let me know. *Crossing fingers* lol and/or comment out any images.

Comment: @Fred you didn't cross them hard enough! It made no difference.

Comment: @SteveGreen Oh crap, would've been nice. Ok, any way you can post your entire source on Pastebin, CSS and all?

Comment: @Fred, there's a lot.  :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33913/discussion-between-steve-green-and-fred)

Comment: Please initially make them display:none, then toggle them.